# Can singletons created using Object keyword be garbage collected in kotlin? Specifically in android

Tags: android, kotlin, garbage-collection

This is the object declaration:

```
object SomeUtility {
 private val someHashMap = hashMapOf(something...)

 fun getSomething(key: Int): String = someHasMap[index]
}
```

And its always being used like this without storing its reference anywhere:
`SomeUtility.getSomething(5)`.

Can this object be garbage collected in Android, if app is running low on memory?

Answer (score 1):

No. The `SomeUtility` is reachable through its name and reachable objects are not garbage collected (exceptions with weak/soft references only apply).